# Angular 7 : Async validator change detection

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous

I've written an async validator to check if the entered email already exists in my database.

I use the reactive form api to build my form and I've configure my async validator to only trigger on "blur". As mentionned in the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance)

it works well: the validation is triggered when I leave the field BUT the error message is not shown until I interact with my form.

If I trigger the changeDetection manually with a setTimeout function in my validation, it works.

Any idea why this error is not shown directly after the validation completes?

Here is my form definition:

```
private initPersonalInformationFormGroup() {
  this.personalInformationFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    gender: [Gender.MALE],
    birthDate: [''],
    birthPlace: [''],
    nationality: [''],
    inss: ['', [Validators.minLength(11), Validators.maxLength(11), Validators.pattern('[0-9]{11}')]],
    email: ['', {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email],
      asyncValidators: [this._studentEmailValidator()],
      updateOn: 'blur'
    }],
    phoneNumber: [null, Validators.pattern('\\+32[1-9][0-9]{7,8}')],
    address: this._formBuilder.group({
      street: ['', [Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      houseNumber: ['', [Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      city: ['', [Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      postalCode: [null, [Validators.min(1000), Validators.max(9999)]],
    }, {
      validators: this._completeAddressValidator()
    }),
    previousSchool: ['', Validators.maxLength(60)],
    additionalInformation: ['']
  })
}
```

And my validation method :

```
private _studentEmailValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormGroup): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
    const email = control.value;
    // setTimeout(() => this._checkDetectorRef.detectChanges(), 5000);
    return this._adminFacade.checkStudentWithEmailExists(email).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(exists => exists ? {'emailAlreadyUserByStudent': {value: email}} : null),
      catchError(() => null)
    );
  }
};
```

and the part of the template :

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="60">
  <mat-placeholder>
    <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
    <span> Email</span>
  </mat-placeholder>
  <input matInput formControlName="email">
  <mat-error *ngIf="email.hasError('emailAlreadyUserByStudent')">
    Email déjà utilisé.
  </mat-error>
  <span *ngIf="email.pending">Validating...</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You should add some of your code otherwise its hard to tell

Comment: Just edited the question with my code.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround (I'm still not sure it's the best way to do it because it's not necessary in the code examples..), I've added a manual detectChanges at the end of my validator function :

```
  private _studentEmailValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
return (control: FormGroup): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
  const email = control.value;
  return this._adminFacade.checkStudentWithEmailExists(email).pipe(
    take(1),
    map(exists => exists ? {'emailAlreadyUserByStudent': {value: email}} : null),
    catchError(() => null),
    tap(() => setTimeout(() => this._checkDetectorRef.detectChanges(), 0))
  );
}
```

};

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, An alternative to `setTimeout()` is to add a `delay(0)` before the `tap` statement, which is basically the same thing, but it's more NgRx, so the cooler kids prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

I just created an observer and you can subscibe on it:

```
export function asyncValidationObserver(abstractControl: AbstractControl): Observable<FormControlStatus> {
    let pending: boolean = false;
    return abstractControl.statusChanges.pipe(
        tap((formControlStatus: FormControlStatus) => {
            if (formControlStatus === 'PENDING') {
                pending = true;
            }
        }),
        filter((formControlStatus: FormControlStatus) => {
            const emit: boolean = pending && (formControlStatus === 'VALID' || formControlStatus === 'INVALID');
            if (formControlStatus !== 'PENDING') {
                pending = false;
            }
            return emit;
        })
    );
}
```

It returns when status changes from PENDING to VALID or INVALID

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
  changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
  //call this when you receive the backend response
  changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

Comment: As mentionned I my post. If I manually trigger the change detection. It works... But I think it should work without this manual action.

Comment: It shouldn't. As you used on push detection, it will automatically work only if some event is triggered inside the component or its children (that's why the message is shown when you interact with the form), if a new value is passed through a @Input or if you trigger it manually. Take a look in the asyncPipe implementation, there is no magic
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/903d28fe86744159582b738cb41e453ec21095c9/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L143

Comment: I don't use "OnPush" detection... (let the defaut)

Comment: You meant changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush ? I'm not setting this on the component...